# In a tabular, how to set a cell text aligned on the right and the text in the below cell aligned with the beginning of the above text

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, columns, alignment

I'd like to obtain a thing similar to the following image[image]

As you see the word "Candidato:" is aligned with the beginning of the name "Giovanni Bianchi", While "Giovanni Bianchi" is aligned to the right.

Moreover I need to put the word "Relatori:" on the same line of "Candidato". "Relatori:" has to be aligned on the left side.

Thank you to everybody can respond to me.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Candidato:\\Giovanni Bianchi\end{tabular}`

Comment: @egreg thank you, I have tried the code, but it doesn't work. Candidato and Giovanni are aligned as I want, but the text goes on the left side, while i want it stays on the right side.

Comment: Of course you need to use `\begin{flushright}...\end{flushright}` around it.

Comment: @egreg thank you again, it works, but the thing I would like to do it is few more complex. I thought I can easily adapt it to my case, but it is not so easy. I've just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're typesetting this in some environment where `\centering` is in force.

You obtain the desired alignment by

```latex
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll@{}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Relatori:\\
Prof.\ Mario Rossi\\
Ing.\ Pietro Verdi
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Candidato:\\
Giovanni Bianchi
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular*}
```

This is precisely what the `frontespizio` package does. It goes without saying that I recommend it.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!, it is what I was looking for. I know frontespizio, but it is not very flexible about many things, so I have preferred to build it to myself. For example I have to write in english my department and course of studies plus the name of my school. Moreover, less important, I do not like the two horizontal lines  on the top and on the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Ruben `\usepackage[norules]{frontespizio}`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I haven't seen this option before. Although I will not use the package, due to the other problems with the language and the several things I have to add under my university name.